# Where do local variables exist?

Tags: c, local-variables

[image: Local variables existence]

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask but I've tried searching everywhere but this question is so specific. I believe local variables exist from **where they are declared to the end of the function** and **from the beginning of the scope to the end of the scope**, is this correct?

Comment: It seems not unreasonable to define "existence" of a variable as its scope.

Comment: So rather it's entire scope rather than where it is declared to the end of the scope? It is the other way around when talking about a function?

Comment: This was my first result for searching "C variable scope": http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: But it's weird to me how a variable exist for the entire scope but not for the entire function, it does not specify the function part

Comment: You still need a definition of "exist".  I think most reasonable people would answer "from where they are declared to the end of the scope", but the question doesn't really make sense.  I would argue that they exist on the local stack frame, only at run time, but that answer is platform dependent.

Comment: This is (obviously) an earlier exam and there is no definition of  "exist". I've always heard that local variables exist for their entire scope though what you say about them existing from where they are declared to the end of the scope makes more sense to me.

Comment: Your question and the options are not really matching. In a typical platform, local variables lives in the stack. Scope of a local variable is from where it is declared till the end of a block.

Comment: @M.M, edited my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  "exist" clearly refers to the time between the start of the variable's lifetime, and its end. The standard defines "lifetime"

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The 2011 C standard defines when an object exists in clause 6.2.4. It is, as M.M notes, the lifetime of the object, not the scope of its identifier.

Answer (score 3):

The best one of the four alternatives is:

> From the beginning of the scope to the end of the scope.

if we assume that "the beginning of the scope" means "the beginning of the block".

Technically the scope of an identifier starts at its declaration. If we took that interpretation then both the first two options are the same, which doesn't make much sense. IMO it is safe to assume that they meant the start of the block.

(The end of the block and the end of the scope are defined as being identical, so there is no issue with the end).

---

The word *exist* clearly refers to the variable's lifetime.  A variable starts to exist when its lifetime begins, and stops existing when its lifetime ends.  The variable's lifetime may differ from the visibility of its identifier; so it is not correct to equate those two things as was suggested in comments.

The lifetime of "local variables" (which is common jargon for non-static variables defined at block scope) is given by 6.2.4/6:

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, **its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way**.

The first answer is the best fit to the bolded text, although the bolded text is more correct because execution does not necessarily enter the block at the start (e.g. `goto`) and execution does not necessarily leave the block at the end (e.g. `break`, `return`).

Since the question asks to select all answers that apply; the first two answers should both be selected. The second answer is a subset of the first one.

The last two are clearly wrong.

---

### Other relevant standard quotes

The definition of *lifetime* is in 6.2.4/2:

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it.

The definition of *scope* in association with blocks is in 6.2.1/4:

> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block.

And is 6.2.1/2:

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called its *scope*.

which clarifies that every identifier has a specific scope (as well as being described as having *block scope*).

Comment: A more interesting example for execution not starting at the beginning of a block may be a switch statement. This may occur more frequently and be a source of bugs more frequently.

Comment: Re “The variable's lifetime may differ from the visibility of its identifier;…” In fact, they cannot be the same since scope is a place and lifetime is a duration in time. They can only be related by viewing execution as a map from time to location—the scope of an identifier may coincide with the locations execution is in during its lifetime. And even then only the locations within the block (so excluding function calls).